# Sementic ui search module with API ISSUE

Tags: jquery, json, user-interface

I need little help for sementic ui search module

i want search input to search in my specified field(name) in my remote json file. if found than display result or show no rsult.

My Sementic ui Script

```
    <script>
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: 'sub/srch_qry.asp?q={query}'
    },
    fields: {
      results : 'results',
      title   : 'name'
    },
    minCharacters : 3
  });
    </script>
```

Input Field

```
<div class="field">
<div class="ui search">
    <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
</div>
```

Json file format

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "Name",
      "name": "guru"
    },
    {
      "title": "Delly",
      "name": "prog"
    }
  ]
}
```

the above codes shows all result in json file no matter what you type in input search field..

Thanks in Advance